# What is going on with this Taylor Series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, taylor-expansion, visualization

I created a program to find high degree Taylor series approximations for any function, but I notice an interesting behavior as higher order polynomials are included. My understanding is that a function such as f(x) = sin(x) is entire, and can be represented infinitely, since it is continuous and differentiable at any point. However, after my Taylor series powers go beyond ~50, the graph becomes hypersensitive and "noisy".

I am posting this to ask if there are flaws in my understanding of these types of power series, or if there is a good explanation of this behavior. I also wonder whether it is preventable in order to obtain a very high order representation of an oscillating function.

I have attached some photos of the described behavior.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsNnH.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzMxU.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPtga.png)

Comment: Could you send Desmos link?

Comment: Presumably, your Taylor Series is a Mclaurin Series (i.e. a Taylor Series expanded about x=0) and so the more periods out you graph the function the more numerical errors (i.e. computer precision rounding limitations) can/will compound.

Comment: the errors in 50th term will be negated by next terms, Maybe 100 terms will negate the error in 50th term, But then , the erros in 100th terms will be negated by next 50 terms and so and so, Even if you reach a very large number of terms, At very large "x", You will still have some noise

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xxhtsgysln

Answer (score 5):

The Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ does converge to $\sin(x)$ for every $x$, but that doesn't mean it is very good in practice for approximating $\sin(x)$.  Consider a particular Taylor polynomial $$S_N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$$
where $f^{(n)}(0) = 1$ for $n = 1, 5, 9, \ldots$, $-1$ for $3, 7, 11, \ldots$, $0$ otherwise. If $N$ is large that is an extremely good approximation to $f(x)$ when $x$ is very close to $0$.  But it is a polynomial of degree $N$ (if $N$ is odd), and so it grows rapidly for large $|x|$, while $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is bounded on the real line.  So if you compare the graphs of $f$ and $S_N$, you should see $S_N$ following $f$ very closely on some interval around $0$ and then shooting off to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ rapidly.  The larger $N$ is, the larger the interval where it is a good approximation.

But that's assuming exact arithmetic.  The terms that made $S_{50}(x)$ large are still present in $S_{100}(x)$, they are just cancelled by other terms.  When you do the calculations numerically, the inevitable rounding errors mean that the cancellation is not exact.  A sum of large numbers of different signs that should almost cancel is a recipe for disaster in numberical work.  That is what produces the
"noisy" result.

EDIT: Here are $\sin(x)$ (blue) with $S_{99}(x)$ (red) and $S_{199}(x)$ (green) as plotted in Maple using Digits = 100 (i.e. $100$ decimal digit arithmetic).  This seems to be enough for the interval in the plot.

[image]

And here is the same with the default setting (which used hardware floating-point, roughly equivalent to $16$ digits).  Note that $S_{99}$ seems to still be OK, but $S_{199}$ gives "chaotic" results for $x > 35$ or so.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I wonder though: is there a way to graph such a high degree polynomial sum (w/ a term such as x^400) without encountering computer rounding errors? I am thinking of a system where a less speedy computation would be performed that results in a cleaner and more exact conclusion. It definitely makes sense that an application like Desmos would struggle with a string (1/200! * (x)^200 + 1/201! * (x)^201 + 1/202! * (x)^202...). Is there any point in this, though? Maybe it would be better to add together split taylor series, each centered around a different X coordinate.

Comment: You can use high-precision arithmetic in a CAS such as Maple. I'll put an example in my answer.

Comment: @Colter Why go with a polynomial approximation at all? Trig functions like Sin and Cos are well implemented in most math/eng software.  Far easier to just take x modulo the period length and plug that into the trig function.

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter Just for the fun of it, and for a programming task. Definitely not practical in any sense, but I found it cool nonetheless.